# How to explain this limit?

Tags: integration, limits, continuity

Let $g(t)$ be a continuous function at $t=0$. Let $A_a$ be the following integral:

$$A_a = \dfrac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}g(t)dt.$$

Now, calculate the limit of $A_a$ as $a$ approaches $0$.

$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{a\to 0}A_a&=\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\dfrac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}g(t)dt\tag{1},\\ &=g(0)\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\dfrac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}dt\tag{2}.
\end{align}
$$

I don't understand how can we go from $(1)$ to $(2)$. In fact, for me, as $a$ approaches $0$, the integral $\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}g(t)dt$ approahces $g(0)$. So the limit should be:
$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{a\to 0}A_a&=g(0)\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\dfrac{1}{a}\tag{3},
\end{align}
$$
but this is wrong.

Comment: Well first of all you need to say that your function is Riemann integrable on every $[c_1; c_2] \subset [-a/2;a/2]$, otherwise your integrals are not defined. And no, you can’t just change the limit and integral: see, you have a $0/0$-type limit, try to use L'Hôpital's rule and when you will differentiate your integral in the numerator, you must use Leibniz integral rule for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zdm

One way to see how you go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ is the following. By continuity at $0$ you have: 
$$
g(t)=g(0)+h(t),
$$
where $h(t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0$.

Then,
$$
\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}g(t)\,dt=\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}[g(0)+h(t)]\,dt
$$
$$
=g(0)+\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}h(t)\,dt.
$$
Now, for any $\epsilon>0$ it is possible to choose $a$ small enough such that $|h(t)|<\epsilon$ for $x\in [-a/2,a/2]$. For such $a$ we have
$$
|\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}h(t)\,dt|\le\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}\epsilon\,dt= \epsilon
$$
thus implying that 
$$
\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{a}|\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}h(t)\,dt|=0
$$
and you finally get 
$$
\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}g(t)\,dt=g(0)
$$
Actually the idea behind is very simple: you are finding the average of a continuous function (at zero) on a sequence of inteervals shrinking to zero. Since the values stabilize around $g(0)$, the average does the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The function $g$ (hence also $h$) should be integrable in a neighborhood of $0$. I'm not sure this is guaranteed only with the assumption that $g$ is continuous at $0$. Surely $g$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, but this doesn't suffice.

Comment: Agree. you have to assume that it Is integrable in some neighborhood of the origin (continuity on some (-delta, delta) would suffice of course.

Answer (score 2):

Best/simplest approach is to use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Let's assume that $g$ is Riemann integrable on some interval of type $[-h, h] $ otherwise your $A_a$ might not be defined.

Consider $$G(x) =\int_{0}^{x}g(t)\,dt$$ Since $g$ is continuous at $0$ it follows by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that $G$ is differentiable at $0$ with $G'(0)=g(0)$.

Now we have
\begin{align*}
L&=\lim _{a\to 0}A_a=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}g(t)\,dt\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^{a}g(t)\,dt\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{G(a)-G(-a)}{2a}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{a\to 0}\left(\frac {G(a)-G(0)}{a}+\frac{G(-a)-G(0)}{-a} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(G'(0)+G'(0))\\
&=G'(0)=g(0)
\end{align*}

Comment: Great explanation! How do you go from $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{a}\int_{\color{red}{-a/2}}^{\color{red}{a/2}}g(t)\,dt$ to $
\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{\color{red}{2a}}\int_{\color{red}{-a}}^{\color{red}a}g(t)\,dt$?. P.S. To avoid having to write `\notag` at the end of each line inside `align` environment you can consider use `align*` environment $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: @manooooh: just replace $a$ by $2a$. Formally it is a substitution $a=2u$ (note that $u\to 0$ as $a\to 0$) and then replace the variable name $u$ by $a$ again. I will edit this to use align* and see how it looks.